# ¿Cómo crear un JSON a partir de elementos obtenidos con getElementById?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy obteniendo desde un archivo `js`, los valores ingresados en unos `inputs`, y necesito saber como hacer un `json`.

```
var X1= document.getElementById('V1').value;
var X2= document.getElementById('v2').value;
var X3= document.getElementById('v3').value;
var X4= document.getElementById('v4').value;
var X5= document.getElementById('v5').value;
```

una vez que este este json, como lo integro a un ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/XXX/XXX?XXX=' ,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
})
    .done(function (lista) {
      ...
    });
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://www.json.org/json-es.html) para conocer la estructura de un JSON. Básicamente: `let objeto = { propiedad1: 'valor1', propiedad2: 'valor2' };` En todo caso, edita la pregunta para agregar información sobre cómo quieres recibir los datos en el servidor para poder sugerir algo.

Answer (score 1):

> necesito saber como hacer un json

Primero aclaremos qué es [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-es.html) para evitar confusiones:

> JSON es un formato de texto que es completamente independiente del lenguaje pero utiliza convenciones que son ampliamente conocidos por los programadores de la familia de lenguajes C, incluyendo C, C++, C#, Java, **JavaScript**

---

Ahora bien, lo que necesitas es enviar un JSON, con los valores de unos inputs que mencionas, en el body de tu request.

Para crear un texto JSON en javascript puedes usar el objeto global [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) para transformar un [objeto Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) en texto con formato JSON.

En tu caso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
var X1= document.getElementById('V1').value;
var X2= document.getElementById('v2').value;
var X3= document.getElementById('v3').value;
var X4= document.getElementById('v4').value;
var X5= document.getElementById('v5').value;

let objetoJavascript = {
  X1: X1, // Aquí puedes cambiar el nombre de la propiedad al que tu necesites
  X2: X2,
  X3: X3,
  X4: X4,
  X5: X5
}; // Este es tu objeto javascript que puede ser convertido a un texto JSON

//Luego lo transformas a un string con formato JSON
let stringJSON = JSON.stringify(objetoJavascript); // Esto es un string con formato JSON
```

La funcion utilizada es [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

---

Por último para enviar ese texto JSON en tu request debes agregar la propiedad `data`:

```javascript
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/XXX/XXX?XXX=' ,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: stringJSON // 
})
  .done(function (lista) {
      ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solamente tienes que agregar el atributo `data` como un objeto que contenga la información que quieres mandar.

No hay mucha información de como quieres que se vea el objeto JSON que buscas enviar pero para fines prácticos puedes seguir este ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/XXX/XXX?XXX=' ,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {X1, X2, X3, X4, X5} 
})
  .done(function (lista) {
      ...
});
```